# docker-compose exited with code 0 - convert docker run command to docker-compose up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to add the DBpedia spotlight API service within docker-compose. (https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/spotlight-docker)

Normally, this command works just fine:

```
docker run -i -p 2222:80 dbpedia/spotlight-english spotlight.sh
```

my attempt at docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  dbpedia:
    image: "dbpedia/spotlight-english:latest"
    ports:
      - "2222:2222"
```

I get the following error when running `docker-compose up`:

```
Recreating composetest_dbpedia_1 ... done
Attaching to composetest_dbpedia_1
composetest_dbpedia_1 exited with code 0
```

What am I missing? I am trying to start DBpedia service like I did before, but as part of the docker-compose file

Answer (score 0):

**Original answer**(check update):

When you execute

```
docker run -i -p 2222:80 dbpedia/spotlight-english spotlight.sh
```

you are explicitly overriding image's default entrypoint.

To achieve the same behavior with docker-compose, try with the following compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  dbpedia:
    image: "dbpedia/spotlight-english:latest"
    ports:
      - "2222:80"
    entrypoint: spotlight.sh
```

You had a mistake with the port mapping which I have corrected.

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint)

---

**UPDATE:** As @David Maze correctly stated in the comments, with your `docker run`command, you are overriding image's `CMD` instruction, so the equivalent docker-compose entry is `command: spotlight.sh`. Obviously, for your image there was no difference but there are cases in which `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` actions are crucial for the image.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I did in fact not read up on entrypoints :) thanks for the link

Comment: Technically you are overriding the command, and the Docker Compose `command:` line is equivalent.  This especially matters in cases where an image uses an entrypoint to do first-time setup and then runs the named command.